# Как в Direct2D получить координаты точки пересечения двух линий?

Tags: graphics, winapi, visual-c++

Пишу приложение Win32 в Visual C++ с использованием Direct2D. Нарисовал две линии, у первой координаты *(x1, y1)*, а у второй — *(x2, y2)*. Вызвал функцию `CompareWithGeometry`, чтобы определить, пересекаются ли эти линии. Функция ответила, что не пересекаются. Повернул первую линию на 20 градусов. Опять вызвал `CompareWithGeometry`. Сказала, что теперь пересекаются.

Мне нужно узнать координаты *(x, y)* точки пересечения. Каким образом я могу это сделать в Direct2D?

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL isIntersectLine(const LPPOINT a1, const LPPOINT a2, 
                     const LPPOINT b1, const LPPOINT b2){
   float t, dot;
   POINT c;
   POINT b = { a2->x - a1->x, a2->y - a1->y };
   POINT d = { b2->x - b1->x, b2->y - b1->y };

   dot = (float)(b.x * d.y - b.y * d.x);
   if(dot == 0.0f)
        return FALSE;

   c.x = b1->x - a1->x;
   c.y = b1->y - a1->y;
   t   = (float)(c.x * d.y - c.y * d.x) / dot;
   if((t < 0.0f) || (t > 1.0f))
        return FALSE;

   t = (float)(c.x * b.y - c.y * b.x) / dot;
   if((t < 0.0f) || (t > 1.0f))
       return FALSE;
   return TRUE;
}
```